# Dynamic Redux Form and MaterializeCSS DatePicker - How do I get the event.target.name of the input?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, materialize, redux-form

I have a form, its a pickup/address form that can have multiple pickups.

Im having trouble figuring out how to get the event.target.name of the input selected to update my state correctly.
In this case, the input names are :
pickups[ 0 ].pickup_date
pickups[ 1 ].pickup_date

```
<FieldArray name="pickups" component={this.renderpickups} />
```

This has a button, "add pickup" that adds another address field group ( date,city,state, etc) using the [documentation](https://redux-form.com/6.0.1/examples/fieldarrays/) of fields.push..

Everytime a new pickup is added,I call a method that re-initalizes Materialize.

How do I get the event.target.name??

```
initializeMaterialCss(){
      let pickupdate = document.querySelectorAll(".loadPickup");

        let pickupdateInstance = M.Datepicker.init(pickupdate, {
          onSelect: this.handleDate,
          autoClose: true
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the below on the Field, and then in the materialize callback, I update redux-form date property(redux-form change method) with the parameters from this react state, and the date value I get from materialize, but it feels hacky.
If there's a better more standard way, please enlighten me.

```
  onFocus={event => this.setState({ focused: event.target.name })}
```